# Ajax Success display Message inside div displayed through jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

i'm trying to display a success /error message when a user login to my website through a hidden div, that is displayed by on click event jQuery. Looks like whatever i try, nothing works. Already searched over and over but can't find a solution. Any help please?

My current code:

```
  $(document).on('submit', '#loginform',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

    $.ajax({
      url: 'portal/login',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType:"json",
      data:formData,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      success: function(data) {
            if(data.status == 1) {
                console.log(data.status);
                $('.login_result.success').show();

            } else {
                $('.login_result.error').show();
            }
        }
    });
});

$('.modaltrigger').on('click',function() {
    $('#loginmodal').fadeIn(500);
});
```

So i'm using Ajax to validate the user login, and then at success i want to fadeIn the .login_result

**EDIT**

My HTML code:

```
<div id="loginmodal" style="display:none;">
<div id="placeHolder">
<div class="main_logo"><img src="images/logo.jpg"></div>
<form action="portal/login" method="post" class="login" name="loginform" id="loginform">
    <input id="user_email" name="user_email" placeholder="Email" type="text">
    <input id="user_password" name="user_password" placeholder="Senha" type="password">
    <button class="search_button login_button" name="admin_login">Entrar</button>
    <span><?php //echo $error; ?></span>
</form>
<div class="login_result success">Login Efetuado com sucesso, Redirecionando!</div>
<div class="login_result error">Login Inválido!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You will have to hide the element before you can fade it in otherwise it has nothing to fade in.

Comment: It is already hidden with display:none

Comment: Can you share the html related to the question please. I think the issue could be how you're trying to target the elements, thank you.

Comment: See if this helps you understand how you can make them fade in :) http://jsfiddle.net/xLp4ffL8/ `$('#placeHolder .success').fadeIn(500);` and `$('#placeHolder .error').fadeIn(500);` should work for you. If not then try change your css to match the one in the jsfiddle example.

Comment: your code works (tested it on jsfiddle). Just be sure of `.login_result { display:none; }`

Comment: I'm angry now, my code is just like yours, but it does not work. maybe because i'm calling the fadeIn on form submit or something?

Comment: Even the console is not returning the values for me, but i'm sure it's working because i get logged in.

Comment: Ok, hold guys, i just tried to use incorrect password and the .error faded in, so what could be happening for the .success to not fadeIn as well?